# Python Excel Worksheet Conditional Formatting Based Off Of Another Sheet

Tags: python, excel, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel Workbook with two sheets:  Sheet 1 and Sheet 2.  I want to color format the cells in column 'B' within Sheet1 based off of column Sheet2 'D'.

```
worksheet.conditional_format("'Sheet1'!B2:C999",
                             {"type": "formula",
                              "criteria": '=Sheet2!($D2=1)',
                              "format": format1
                             }
```

I have this code working on the same sheet, so I know I am very close, but when trying to format it for another I get a very generic 'NoneType' error.

Comment: `=Sheet2!($D2=1)` doesn't look like a valid formula. Try `'=Sheet2!$D2=1'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head against the wall for hours, I found the solution in only a few minutes.  Here is the solution:

```
worksheet.conditional_format('B2:C999', {'type': 'formula',
                                       'criteria': '=Sheet2!$D2=1', 
                                       'format': format1})
```